# How To get xml node from object of type T?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlnode

I am trying to convert the object of type T into xml node because I want to display the xml node in a wpf control. Below is the linqpad snippet, I am working with:

```
[Serializable]
public class test {
public int int1  { get ; set ;}
public int int2 { get ; set ;} 
public string str1 { get ; set ;}
}

void Main()
{
test t1 = new test () ;
t1.int1 = 12 ;
t1.int2 = 23 ;
t1.str1 = "hello" ;


System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new  System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(t1.GetType());
StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
 XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
 x.Serialize(writer, t1);
 var xml = sww.XmlSerializeToXElement (); 
 xml.Dump () ;

}
```

I am not getting intended result and instead, I am getting this:

```
<StringWriter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NewLine>
</NewLine>
</StringWriter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to get an `XElement`, the `xml.Root` is what you want:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(t1.GetType());
StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
x.Serialize(writer, t1);
var xml = XDocument.Parse(sww.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(xml.Root);
```

Output:

```
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <int1>12</int1>
  <int2>23</int2>
  <str1>hello</str1>
</test>
```